# How to inherit the output of toString() and to append additional text?

Tags: java, inheritance, tostring, overriding

So... I have a parent class which overrides default toString() method and another class which inherits (extends) the first class. 
Is there a way to override toString() method of the second class so it just to append text next to the output of toString() method of its parental class? 
 This is the code of the parental class:
`@Override
    public String toString(){
    return String.format("First Name: %s%nLast Name: %s", getFirstName(), getLastName());
    }`

 
I would like just to append `Facility number: %s` at the end of the string.

Comment: Yes. Post your code.

Comment: Something like `public String toString(){return super.toString() + "additonal part";}`?

Comment: Thank you. It works :) I guessed that it will be something similar to the constructor invocation with "super" but I didn't know how to write it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get use **super** before toString() method. It let you use method from base class. The word **this** give you method from class which is extended by base class.